# Vector space and dimension

Tags: vector-spaces

Determine if the following vector systems in the spaces indicated
are or are not bases:

x1 = (1, 1, −1), x2 = (1, 2, 3), x3 = (1, 0, 1) in R
3

Where I can find a good information with  subject vector space, base, dimensions? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Are they linearly independent? Since the dimension of your space is 3, and you have 3 vectors, it suffices to show that they are linearly independent. If they are not linearly independent then they aren't a basis.

Answer (score 1):

A basis is a linearly independent spanning set.

A set of vectors being *linearly independent* means that you cannot construct any of the vectors as a linear combination of any of the other ones; or equivalently, that the only linear combination that vanishes is the trivial combination. In symbols: $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent if $$c_{1}v_{1}+c_{2}v_{2}+\ldots c_{n}v_{n} = 0$$ implies that $c_1=c_2=\ldots c_n=0.$

A set of vectors being a *spanning set* means that any vector in your space (in this case, $\mathbb{R}^3,$ can be written as a linear combination of these vectors.

Theorem: A linearly independent set of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Since you have 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ you only need to check that they are linearly independent. The easiest way to do this is to create a matrix with the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ as the columns of your matrix, and row reduce your matrix. If you get the identity matrix, your vectors are in fact linearly independent, and if you cannot get the identity matrix, then the vectors are linearly dependent.